# How to copy and rename an external file from SAS EG without x/system command?

Tags: sas

I have a template for a report in a folder on our server, and instead of copying the template into a new directory every time I need to run a report, I'm looking automate it in SAS.

I have tried using `x` command and `system()` as below:

`data _null_;
  rc = system('copy "\\servername\Reports\Reporting Templates\Template.xlsm" "\\servername\Output\Template_new.xlsm")
put rc =;
run;`

but I run into the error `ERROR: Shell escape is not valid in this SAS session.`, which appears to be security related and I need admin rights to activate the option.

Then from google searching, I came across https://www.sas.com/content/dam/SAS/en_ca/User%20Group%20Presentations/TASS/Jia_Lin_Manage_External_Files_June2015.pdf
which mentions using the `rename()` function within a SAS data step to rename an external file (and copy to a new folder, the author claims). However, I cannot get it to work.

`data _null_;
  rc = rename("\\servername\Reports\Reporting Templates\Template.xlsm", 
              "\\servername\Reports\Reporting Templates\Template_new.xlsm",
              "file");
put rc=;
run;`

When I check the log, I have no errors and `rc` has a value of 1 which, according to the documentation, means that it was executed successfully, but the file name has not changed.

I have also tried this in different folders and ondifferent file types to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tested your code on my own machine and was successful renaming an Excel file on my desktop. It may be related to write permissions on your server. I would also recommend contacting an admin to enable `x` commands on your SAS server. It will greatly expand what you can do in SAS.

Comment: Thanks for that Stu. It's strange, as I can write from SAS to the same folder, and rename files from the command line, or within file explorer but the above code doesn't work.

Comment: Does SAS `FCOPY` work ?  If so, fcopy followed by fdelete would be same result as rename()

Comment: ^^ agreed with @Richard

Comment: Thank you all for you help, FCOPY does work, and actually does what I originally needed to do which was copy AND rename. Will double check my code for any issues using rename()

Comment: There turned out to be a mistake in one of the two server name strings, when I corrected it the above method worked - but I have decided to use `FCOPY` thanks @Richard

Comment: if FCOPY doesn't work, try this generic filecopy macro: https://github.com/macropeople/macrocore/blob/master/base/mp_binarycopy.sas

Answer (score 2):

It's possible your SAS session is locked down and unable to modify files except in a few locations.  From the [SAS documentation](http://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.3&docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p14axci3mo3egan1okbcydvbt433.htm&locale=en) on `RENAME()`

> If the SAS session in which you are specifying the FILEEXIST function
>   is in a locked-down state, and the pathname specified in the function
>   has not been added to the lockdown path list, then the function will
>   fail and a file access error related to the locked-down data will not
>   be generated in the SAS log unless you specify the SYSMSG function.

1. Good job, SAS Documentation team for not changing `FILEEXIST` to `RENAME` during your copy and paste.
2. Use the `SYSMSG()` function to see if there is an error that is not being propagated to the log.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was a mistake in the server name, but I think @DomPazz's answer is still useful and the comments provided me with several alternatives that would form a suitable answer to this question:

**1. Rename statement**

```
data _null_;
  rc = rename("\\servername\Reports\Reporting Templates\Template.xlsm",
              "\\servername\Output\Template_new.xlsm",
              "file");
  put rc=;
run;
```

**2. FCOPY with filename statements**

*NOTE*: When I used `FCOPY` to move a macro-enabled worksheet (.xlsm) it corrupted the file and I had to recopy it with `rename()`

```
filename src "\\servername\Reports\Reporting Templates\Template.xlsm",
filename dest "\\servername\Output\Template_new.xlsm"   

data _null_;
  rc = fcopy('src', 'dest');
  put rc=;
run;
```

**3. Binary Copy**
Another method that I haven't test, but copies files over in chunks Rather than byte by byte. One that uses the `%mp_binarycopy()` macro. Github repo is here:
https://github.com/sasjs/core/blob/main/base/mp_binarycopy.sas

And another similar method described in this SAS blog post, with link to code:
https://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/files/2013/09/binaryfilecopy.sas_.txt